# Why does PyQt5 QtMultimedia gives an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Using OS: Linux Ubuntu 18.04

I'm trying to run different PyQt examples that contain QtMultimedia module.
Unfortunately, they give me the same error:

> defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for -
>   "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"

I've heard that many people, who use Unix-like OS, have faced with that problem but i still can't find any solution.

Here's a code sample:`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia
import sys

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent, flags=
        QtCore.Qt.Window | QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setWindowTitle("Music PLayer")

        #   Player
        self.mpPlayer = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.mpPlayer.setVolume(50)
        self.mpPlayer.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.initPlayer)
        self.mpPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.setPlayerState)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        #   File open button
        btnOpen = QtWidgets.QPushButton("File &open")
        btnOpen.clicked.connect(self.openFile)
        vbox.addWidget(btnOpen)

        #   Make components disable at start
        self.sldPosition = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.sldPosition.setMinimum(0)
        self.sldPosition.valueChanged.connect(self.mpPlayer.setPosition)
        self.mpPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.sldPosition.setValue)
        self.sldPosition.setEnabled(False)
        vbox.addWidget(self.sldPosition)

        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.btnPlay = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Play")
        self.btnPlay.clicked.connect(self.mpPlayer.play)
        self.btnPlay.setEnabled(False)
        hbox.addWidget(self.btnPlay)

        self.btnPause = QtWidgets.QPushButton("P&ause")
        self.btnPause.clicked.connect(self.mpPlayer.pause)
        self.btnPause.setEnabled(False)
        hbox.addWidget(self.btnPause)

        self.btnStop = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Stop")
        self.btnStop.clicked.connect(self.mpPlayer.stop)
        self.btnStop.setEnabled(False)
        hbox.addWidget(self.btnStop)

        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        #    Volume control
        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        lblVolume = QtWidgets.QLabel("&Volume")
        hbox.addWidget(lblVolume)

        sldVolume = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        sldVolume.setRange(0, 100)
        sldVolume.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.TicksAbove)
        sldVolume.setTickInterval(10)
        sldVolume.setValue(50)
        lblVolume.setBuddy(sldVolume)
        sldVolume.valueChanged.connect(self.mpPlayer.setVolume)
        hbox.addWidget(sldVolume)

        btnMute = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Mute")
        btnMute.setCheckable(True)
        btnMute.toggled.connect(self.mpPlayer.setMuted)
        hbox.addWidget(btnMute)

        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.resize(300, 100)


    def openFile(self):
        file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileUrl(parent=self,
                                                    caption="Choose track file",
                                                    filter="Medial files (*.mp3 *.ac3)")
        self.mpPlayer.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(file[0]))

    def initPlayer(self, state):
        if state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.LoadedMedia:
            self.mpPlayer.stop()
            self.btnPlay.setEnabled(True)
            self.sldPosition.setEnabled(True)
            self.slfPosition.setMaximum(self.mpPlayer.duration())
        elif state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.EndOfMedia:
            self.mpPlayer.stop()
        elif state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.NoMedia or state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.InvalidMedia:
            self.sldPosition.setValue(0)
            self.sldPosition.setEnabled(False)
            self.btnPlay.setEnabled(False)
            self.btnPause.setEnabled(False)
            self.btnStop.setEnabled(False)


    def setPlayerState(self, state):
        if state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.StoppedState:
            self.sldPosition.setValue(0)
            self.btnPause.setEnabled(False)
            self.btnStop.setEnabled(False)
        elif state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.btnPause.setEnabled(True)
            self.btnStop.setEnabled(True)
        elif state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PausedState:
            self.btnPause.setEnabled(False)
            self.btnPlay.setEnabled(True)

def main():
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

`

Comment: execute: `sudo apt-get install libqtgstreamer-dev && sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5-plugins`

Comment: @eyllanesc, libqt5multimedia5-plugin has been already installed, and there is no way to install libqtgstreamer-dev. Seems like it doesn't exist in the universe repository.

Comment: execute: `apt-cache search *qtgstreamer*` or `apt-cache search *gstreamer*`

Comment: what is the output of `apt-cache search *qtgstreamer*` or `apt-cache search *gstreamer*`?

Comment: @eyllanesc, thanks for the advice. Unfortunatelly, it still doesn't work. Also, I've tried to run the code with Pyside2 and it works!
I really can't understand why does it hapen cause in QMediaPlayer.py they both adress to the same directory to QtMultimedia.so.
And I'm pretty confused with this file. All it's functions are empty. (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IJFDOEXPxkVtqM-i2NhjOCWIY2TSrJ60)

Comment: That is correct, PyQt5 is not written in python, it is an interface of Qt5, that is to say the logic of Qt5 is used that is written in C ++, so those functions are not implemented, so do not worry or alarming about it. On the other hand, the last thing I asked for is not intended to solve your problem, but you inform me what packages you have installed and then I could indicate that you are missing, so if you do not tell me what you get with the previous commands I will not be able to help.

Comment: @eyllanesc, Here's the output:
`libqt5glib-2.0-0`, `libqt5gstreamer-1.0-0`, `libqt5gstreamer-dev`, `libqt5gstreamerquick-1.0-0`, `libqt5gstreamerui-1.0-0` `libqt5gstreamerutils-1.0-0` `qml-module-qtgstreamer` `qtgstreamer-doc` `qtgstreamer-plugins-qt5`

Comment: try installing this packages

Comment: I have a question, how have you installed PyQt5?

Comment: In that link show several ways to install, you have to be concrete, which of the methods you used ?, If you do not want to have problems I recommend you to uninstall PyQt5 and install via linux repos, in your case: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 python-pyqt5`

Comment: As I said uninstall it, and use the pyqt5 that your distro gives you. to uninstall, use `sudo pip unistall python-pyqt5`, and to install the pyqt5 of your distribution use: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 python-pyqt5`

Comment: @eyllanesc, well, now i have a new error. My IDE can't find QtMultimedia at all.
I'm thinking to stop at this point, cause the solving of this issue already has taken so long.
I'll return to PySide2. It works well on my machine. 
Anyway, thanks a lot for help!